# Regex for finding numbers with or without a comma - but no other trailing symbols

Tags: python, regex, excel-formula

I need a regex that will parse a string and give me all of the numbers in it EXCEPT for things like percentage or currency.

So for example:

```
Mario is 1,400 - which is 16% older than Luigi --> 1,400
Mario is 1400 - which is 500 years older than peach ---> 1400 500
Peach is 20% older than Luigi at 5000 and owes him 25$ ---> 5000
```

The closest I have gotten is here: https://regex101.com/r/4wkttj/1

```
\b\d+(?:[\.,]\d+)?\b\s+(?!%|percent)
```

which gives me the first instance correctly, but not the second. additionally, If I try to put it in excel I get an error that the regex is invalid (even though it works fine on regex testing sites).

```
=REGEXMATCH(A5, "\b\d+(?:[\.,]\d+)?\b\s+(?!%|percent)")
Function REGEXMATCH parameter 2 value "\b\d+(?:[\.,]\d+)?\b\s+(?!%|percent)" is not a valid regular expression.
```

Comment: Why the need for regex? You can try splitting the string and only keep numbers without % or $.

Comment: @BernardL am looking for a way to automate for large sets of data. If you have a suggestion of how to do this in excel/sheets using the above method I am open to it.

Comment: Couple of points here - 1. I'm assuming you mean Google Sheets instead of Excel because I see that function to be in Sheets Documentation. 
2. Google Sheets uses [re2](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/main/doc/syntax.txt) which is why you were getting the compilation differences
3. re2 [doesn't support negative lookahead](https://github.com/google/re2/issues/156) as exampled in your regex.

Comment: Also, about it giving the first match correctly but not the second, you just need to set 'global' option in your regex matcher (for regex101 you can find it on the right of the regex input), rest of your regex looks good for PCRE for what you were trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regular expression

```
\d+,?\d+(?![%$])
```

or

```
[0-9,]+(?![0-9%$])
```

Comment: Yang this is almost there but it will allow for 3,000%  (percentage with comma)

https://regex101.com/r/Yq9HcJ/1

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, one way without regex and pure `str` operations:

```
lines = ['Mario is 1,400 - which is 16% older than Luigi',
         'Mario is 1400 - which is 500 years older than peach',
         'Peach is 2,000% older than Luigi at 5000 and owes him 25$']

for line in lines:
    sub = []
    for word in line.split():
        if any(i.isdigit() for i in word) and (word.strip("$%") == word):
            sub.append(word)
    print(line, "-->", sub)
```

Output:

```
Mario is 1,400 - which is 16% older than Luigi --> ['1,400']
Mario is 1400 - which is 500 years older than peach --> ['1400', '500']
Peach is 2,000% older than Luigi at 5000 and owes him 25$ --> ['5000']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
\b\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?\b(?!\s+(?:%|percent))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4wkttj/2).

The `(?!\s+(?:%|percent))` part makes a difference here. The `\s+` is moved into the lookahead and the `%` and `percent` alternatives are grouped, so that the `\s+` could be applied to both.

Note that a `.` char inside a character class is not special, there is no need escaping it there.

**More details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `(?:[.,]\d+)?` -  an optional sequence of a `.` or `,` and then one or more digits
- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?!\s+(?:%|percent))` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if - immediately to the right of the current location - there are

  - `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
  - `(?:%|percent)` - `%` or `percent` strings.

Answer (score 0):

Ortal and I chatted about this on the side but I wanted to post what I was able to work out here for posterity. Still wasn't able to get percentages with commas to run smoothly but was able to solve for the other variables in a way that gets along with RE2 / Excel / Sheets.

```
(?:[^$0-9,])(?:\d+[,.]*\d+|\d+)(?:[0-9]+[^%])
```

Probably a much leaner way to write this but seems to work in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather long but should catch most of the edge cases surrounding odd decimals and thousands-delimiter, currency-or-percentage symbols before or after.

I have included more use cases that might trip up other solutions.

See that in action here - note you will have to look at the capture group 1 (`\\1` or `$1`) to extract the numeric-only portion.  You will also have to parse "," and "." to get a true number, but most text-to-number functions can do this.

https://regexr.com/78hre

```js
/\b(?<![\$\%\.\d])([\d\.\,]+)\b\.?(?![\$\%\.\d])/g
```

Note that it does require negative lookbehind support in your regex implementation, but that has decent browser and language support and python should support it in whatever implementation you're using it on.

[image: sample input text, and list of matches]